# JQuery plugin to modify timespan

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, timespan

Is there a good JQuery plugin to work with timespans?

I'm working on a countdown/timer style app and I want to be able to do stuff like create a timer that counts down from 5 hours.

Thanks

Comment: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Comment: @PratikJoshi Thanks but that depends on the date object. I want something that is independent of the datetime and deals strictly with just timespan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, found a good match on GitHub: https://github.com/mstum/TimeSpan.js